# adb restore progress

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, backup, adb

Using the backup and restore function with adb (as discussed in [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices/28315#28315)) there is no progress available and often it is very hard to follow the `adb logcat` output as long there are much more background events than the `BackupManager`.

While backups often takes up to 1.5 hours (on my Nexus7) and restore often gets stuck or takes up to 2h i'm asking myself

is there a (native, i.e. w/o root) way to

- get a progress while taking a backup
- progress on restore
- statistics (bytes written per second), estimated time for backup/restore etc.

any tools (adb wrapper?!) available to archive this?

Comment: You can provide a filter spec to `adb logcat` so you just see the BackupManager output.  I think "adb logcat BackupManager" will do it, but I can't find doc on the filter spec ..

Comment: yes, but as I noticed some apps are throwing errors while backup what isn't recognized by BackupManager. BackupManager often tells me "all things went fine in the end" even if most operations failed.. so filtering for "BackupManager" will not help as I can see

Answer (score 5):

`adb logcat` outputs the `BackupManager` activities, so you can monitor if the process is running or stalled. Since `adb logcat` produces lots of logs from other processes, it is not easy to watch `BackupManager` logs. The easy way to watch BackupManager output is to use grep.

`adb logcat | grep BackupManager`

will filter only `BackupManager` logs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a system monitor tool that shows the activity of the disk/processes.
In windows you can use Resource Monitor, other systems, such as Linux vary.
The general idea is to know that there is some data being read/written from the system to the Android device.